# MySQL creating first table

Tags: mysql, key

I'm going to use MySQL for database for a Java-program.
The Java-program is going to contain a muscle and workout-exercise directory.
To store information about muscles I've made a table called "muscles".
The primary key in this table is supposed to be name of the muscle.
But also it should contain the following data:
-which bodypart the muscle belongs to
-which muscleheads it contains
.which movement activates it
-which muscles are related to it

For the primary key I would like some kind of string value, I would had guessed Varchar() is what I'm looking for, but MySQL doesn't let me choose it for primary key. And now I'm a bit confused after realising how many types I can choose from, which would be the optimal choice.
I would guess the one called "Text" or "Tinytext" would be optimal, can you confirm this as a right choice?

Comment: Dropping the `[java]` tag as it doesn't appear to be Java specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [varchar() primary key or int primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815070/varchar-primary-key-or-int-primary-key)

Comment: use an integer.  it is much more efficient

Comment: @Randy but will it work using integer when the names aren't numbers? Or is there some smart way of getting pass that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're question does not truly specifiy enough information to come up with a true data model, but to start you would not want to have the Muscle name or some other string value as a primary key. To make it simple and with the knowledge that you would not have more than 1000 records in this table. I would start with this.

1 table with all the main muscles uniquely identified by an Int that you can assign as you build your data, that's your PK on Table 1. I would also have a Muscle group in this table that is a FK to a Table with all the Muscle Groups that contain Muscleheads.

1 Table with each and every Musclehead that is related by PK/FK to the first table and also contains Body part information.

1 Table with the excercise information that relates to Muscleheads and ultimatley Muscles in the first table.. By virtue of PK relationships.

The idea is you start with a High level base of Muscles. Since Muscle groups are a way to collect and group these muscles you want that ability in this table. Then  whenever you get to a 1:n relationship you basically need another table that has a Primary key relationship to the high level base table.

Hence -  Muscles: Muscleheads or Muscleheads:Excercise activitys

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand the part about using an integer primary key, I'll try to make it as you suggest :)